# git hooks bash -- getting the commit message

Tags: git, bash

I am writing a git hook, to run on a commit to the main branch. I need it to parse and look for some text in the the commit message. How do I reference the commit message in my bash script?

Also I would like to know how to run the hook only on commits to the main branch. so developers can quash there local commits and commit to  the main branch when they have fixed a bug or something.

Please and thank you.

Comment: I'm confused about "quash their local commits and commit to the main branch when they have fixed a bug or something" - does that mean that only these infrequent commits to master need to be verified, or that other things need to be verified only when they're merged to master? (And really, bugfixes should often be on their own topic branches initially.)

Comment: only the infrequent commits need to be verified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends slightly on what you're trying to do with the commit message. There are three hooks you could be asking about:

- `prepare-commit-msg` is run immediately after the default message is prepared, before the user edits it. The first argument is the name of the file with the commit message. (The second argument indicates where the message came from.)
- `commit-msg` is run after the commit message is edited/finalized, but before the commit takes place. If you want to fail the commit if the user's commit message is bad, or to modify the message, you want this, and the single argument is the name of the file with the commit message.
- `post-commit` is run after the commit. It has no arguments, but you can of course get the message from `git log -n 1 HEAD` (probably with `--format=format:%s%n%b` or some such). If all you want to do is look for something in the message, and notify based on it, you should use this.

All of this material is taken from the [githooks manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

As for running it only on the main branch, all you need is something like:

```
if [ "$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)" == "refs/head/master" ]; then
    # do your stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

With following command:

`cat $1`

will print your commit message in commit-msg